# Coldfusion10 Solr cfindex data import different to DataImportHandler, How to configure data-config.xml?

Tags: coldfusion, solr, dataimporthandler, coldfusion-10, dih

i am trying to get a solr search working with Coldfusion10. I have used the build in Solr install and created the collection using the CF Admin. It creates a schema.xml that should work with cfindex and cfsearch etc.

First i wrote a import script in coldfusion, fetich the data with a query and giving it to solr using cfindex.

```
<cfquery name="myList" datasource="#db#" dbtype="#dbtype#">
    SELECTT TOP 20000 prodID,name,desc,accountID,shopID,ean,isbn
    FROM products
</cfquery>

<cfindex action="update" collection="testcollection" query="myList" type="custom" status="info" 
            key="prodID"   
            title="name"
            body="desc"  
            accountID_i=accountID
            shopID_i=shopID
            ean_s="ean"
            isbn_s="isbn"
            />
```

This works good but not fast enough. I can search perfectly, it is giving my suggestedQuery results if i mispell something in my search criteria. E.g. Searching for "pleystation" suggestiong "playstation" etc.

After that wanted to give the Data Import Hanlder von Solr a try. I got everything to work, the databank connection, all the basic config files to start the full import.

The indexing was very fast, but it was not giving me any suggestions etc. 
I am sure i have not configured the data-import.xml file correctly. 
The problem is, that i don t Know how Coldfusion10 deals with the files that i give into the cfindex tag and sends it to solr.

Here is one of my data-config.xml files that i have tried.

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" type="JdbcDataSource" url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.1:1234/myDatabase;DatabaseName=myDatabase;" user="test" password="test"/>
<document name="products">
    <entity name="products" query="SELECT TOP 20000 prodID,name,desc,accountID,shopID,ean,isbn FROM products">
        <field column="prodID" name="uid"/>
        <field column="prodID" name="key"/>
        <field column="name" name="title"/>
        <field column="desc" name="body"/>
        <field column="accountID" name="accountid_i"/>
        <field column="shopID" name="shopid_i"/>
        <field column="ean" name="ean_s"/>
        <field column="isbn" name="isbn_s"/>
    </entity>
</document></dataConfig>
```

It looks like by using the DIH Solr does not process the content in the same way it is done when using cfindex. I tried to play with different field names from the by cf created schema.xml like contests etc but that did not help.

Any help or suggestions for this problem would be great :)

Greetings Markus

Answer (score 1):

There is some difference when you are indexing it with DIH. Like key, Custom fields and categories are not available. DIH is mostly limited to indexing DB and only 3 attributes are required *collection,type,action*. If you are using DIH then no need to provide a file to cfindex. You just need to put data-config.xml to collection's folder.

Other then suggestions how DIH Solr is there any other inconsistency you observed?

Thanks
Kunal

Comment: "Like key, Custom fields and categories are not available." Wouldn't they be available if you modified the data-config and schema files? I think you mean not available in the function call.